# Two NVMe devices appearing as one

Tags: nvme

When I run `lsblk` I see that I have two NVMe devices:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1                259:0    0   1.1T  0 disk  /home
nvme1n1                259:1    0   1.1T  0 disk
```

But `df -h` presents a single NVMe device with `2.2T` of space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/nvme0n1                2.2T  551G  1.7T  25% /home
```

When I run `strings` on the two devices shows that they have the same data:

```
$ sudo strings /dev/nvme0n1 | head

$ sudo strings /dev/nvme1n1 | head
```

So it seems that somehow `/dev/nvme0n1` and `/dev/nvme1n1` are being merged together as a single device. What could be the cause of this?